# How to concatenate excel files just by getting the specific sheet name from gdrive using google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Can someone help me on this? I'am trying to combined all the excel files from gdrive using google colab just by getting all the specific sheet name only. Btw, each files I have contains 3 sheets and I just wanted to get only this sheet name = "data". TIA!

Here's my sample code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
os.chdir("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Reports/2022")

extension = "xlsx"
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_data = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name="data") for f in all_filenames ])

#export to excel
combined_data.to_excel("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Reports Running 2022.xlsx", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Then after running this code I get a ValueError: No objects to concatenate like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Gyh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Reports/2022"
# pull files with `.xlsx` extension
workbooks = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".xlsx")]
sheets = ["data"]
# Filter sheet when sheet_name == "data"
df_dicts = {
    sh: pd.concat(
        [pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, wb), sheet_name=sh) 
         for wb in workbooks]
    )
    for sh in sheets
}

#export to single file
with pd.ExcelWriter('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/ReportsRunning2022.xlsx') as writer:
   for sh, df in df_dict.items(): 
       df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sh, index=False)

   writer.save()
```